# Using NServiceBus with multiple application both act as Publisher and Subscriber

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I'm trying to use NServiceBus to make 4 applications communicating together.

All these applications have to act as Publisher and Subscriber.

The only way i founded ti get it workiing is to create a "master" queue named Server, on 
which MessageEndpointMappings in all applications configuration is mapped to, but i think it's not the good way ...

So how should i configure NServiceBus on all these application to get this working ?

Application 1 :

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyApp1" ErrorQueue="Errors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="Subscriptions" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MyApp.Messages" Endpoint="Server" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Application 2 :

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyApp2" ErrorQueue="Errors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="Subscriptions" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MyApp.Messages" Endpoint="Server" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Application 3 :

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyApp3" ErrorQueue="Errors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="Subscriptions" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MyApp.Messages" Endpoint="Server" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Application 4 :

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyApp4" ErrorQueue="Errors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="Subscriptions" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MyApp.Messages" Endpoint="Server" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Comment: So then, regardless of message type, you want every application to be able to publish a message, and have all four applications (including the publisher) then receive that message?  If not, what is the true goal?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the business requirements behind you communication needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServiceBus prefers you follow the pattern of a particular message type being published by one service only. Typically you will have a 'messages' assembly for each service, eg:

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="MyApp1" ErrorQueue="Errors" NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
  <MsmqSubscriptionStorageConfig Queue="MyApp1Subscriptions" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MyApp2.Messages" Endpoint="MyApp2" />
      <add Messages="MyApp3.Messages" Endpoint="MyApp3" />
      <add Messages="MyApp4.Messages" Endpoint="MyApp4" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

If you want to publish the same message type from all four applications, you can Bus.Send() the message to a central event publisher service, which could then Bus.Publish() it.